# Using multiple stages with multiple environment variables AWS Lambda with circle CI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, circleci, serverless

We are developing an API for a mobile application and this should have two stages as dev and prod. Also, this must have separate environment variables to connect with databases and store SNS keys. How to do this with Circle CI and aws lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two (that I can think of) options when dealing with stages with `AWS lambdas`, the single `AWS` account path and the `AWS` account/stage path. Both rely on the immutability of the environment variables after a version is released.

Basically, once you are happy with a version of your lambda code, you can issue a command to `AWS` using the `CLI` from your `Circle CI` job to create a version. This effectively creates a snapshot of the lambda with all its environments variables. After that, you can create an alias to point to this new version also using `Circle CI`. All your services that rely on this `lambda` should point to the alias, not to a specific version to avoid having to update them for every release.

This works for both single and multi account solutions. The difference lies in how you reference a version of a `lambda` depending on the environment.

Single account route: you would create an alias for each stage, in your case, `dev` and `prod`. The steps would look as follows:

1. Change the code of your `lambda` for the new version.
2. Update the environment variables required for the new version for the `dev` environment.
3. Release a new version of your `lambda`. This would fix the environment variables that you specified for that version.
4. Update your dev alias to point to this new version and test it. If there is a problem, you can always rollback to the previous version used in `dev`.
5. Modify the environment variables for your `prod` environment in the `$LATEST` version of your `lambda`.
6. Follow steps 3 and 4 but using `prod` as alias.

   Multi account route: here the alias is basically used to point to the new version once it has been properly tested (or to actually test it using a `canary release` for example), regardless of the environment.
7. Follow steps 1 to 4 from the single account route in the `dev` account. Use whatever you like as alias. `prod` could work for both accounts or, if you use `blue/green deployment`, you can use blue and green as alias to reference the current version in test and the current live one.
8. Follow steps 1 to 4 from the single account route in the `prod` account. Same approach as before for the alias.

Personally, I prefer the multi account route. It simplifies the code if your environment variables come from another service like `Systems Manager Parameter Store`. In the single account option, you would still need to pass the stage as a variable to then use it to fetch the proper value from `Parameter Store` (something like dbpass_dev and dbpass_prod). Then you would also have to put something in place in `Parameter Store` to limit the access to each variable depending on whether they are for the dev or for the prod environment. This can be done using policies and tags but it's more complicated.